# Сложный слайдер slick

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

Есть задание сделать слайдер. Вот такого типа.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я хотел использовать для его создания slick slider. но не пойму как вставить заголовок НОЯБРЬ в слайдер. Пока функционал не нужен никакой.

Может кто знает?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.preview-slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-btn slick-btn-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',
    vertical: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    infinite: false
  });



});
```

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.preview-block {
  width: 220px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.preview-block p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #555360;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.date-of-month {
  min-width: 25px;
  max-width: 25px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info-date {
  padding: 7px 8px;
}

.slick-btn {
  height: 46px;
  background-color: #7469b1;
  width: 220px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.slick-btn-top:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.slick-slide {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>My test</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.8.0/slick.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.8.0/slick.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>



  <h2>Ноябрь</h2>

  <div class="preview-slider">


    <div data="november">
      <div class="preview-block">
        <div class="date-of-month">
          <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info-date">
          <p>Панельная дискуссия «Особенности заключения государственных контрактов…</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div data="november">
      <div class="preview-block">
        <div class="date-of-month">
          <p>2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info-date">
          <p>Российский форум по системам искусственного интеллекта – RAIF</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div data="november">
      <div class="preview-block">
        <div class="date-of-month">
          <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info-date">
          <p>Научно-техническая и практическая конференция «Перспективы развития…</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div data="december">
      <div class="preview-block">
        <div class="date-of-month">
          <p>4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info-date">
          <p>Панельная дискуссия «Особенности заключения государственных контрактов…</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div data="december">
      <div class="preview-block">
        <div class="date-of-month">
          <p>5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info-date">
          <p>Российский форум по системам искусственного интеллекта – RAIF</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div data="december">
      <div class="preview-block">
        <div class="date-of-month">
          <p>6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info-date">
          <p>Научно-техническая и практическая конференция «Перспективы развития…</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='slick/slick.min.js'></script>

</html>
```

Comment: обычная вёрстка ... есть `vertical-center-4` внутри блоки внутри которых img вместо них вставляете блоки любой сложности - стилизуете ...вопрос на оценку junior

Comment: так это мы получим слайды. А заголовок прикрутить к этим слайдам пока не получается.

Comment: lenovonuj@gmail.com  пишите - сюда лень выкладывать и пост удалите

Comment: Решено!!! Если кому интересно скину данные.

Comment: ты бы в ответ данные скинул...